# ui-sref not changing template because of state behaving like a child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using ui-sref and trying to change the state in the main.js file. The url changes to the corresponding state but template doesn't.
What actually I am trying to do is to change the state in main.js file which uses a template having ui-view from another home.js file. ui-view runs correctly in case of my "main" state but it fails in case of "create-patient" state and returns the template from the "main" state.

Here are my code snippets :

```
<a ui-sref="createPatient"> * Click here to create a Patient Record * </a>
```

**main.js**

```
.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
"ngInject";
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  template: require('./main.html')
});

$stateProvider.state('createPatient', {
  url: '/create-patient',
  template: require('./mainCreatePatient.html')
})
```

})

**main.html**

```
<div>
  <header-component></header-component>
</div><br/>
<div>
  <breadcrumbs-component></breadcrumbs-component>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="home" id="body-wrapper" ui-view="homePage">
</div>
```

**mainCreatePatient.html**

```
<div>
  <header-component></header-component>
</div><br/>


<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="home" id="body-wrapper" ui-view="patientCreate">
</div>
```

**home.js**

```
.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
    "ngInject";
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/',
      views : {
        "homePage@" : {
          template: require('./home.html')
        },
        "patientCreate@" : {
          template : require('./patientCreatePage.html')
        }
      }
    });
})
```

I am just stuck at this and don't know whether there might be any better way to do this or not. Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: In the `createPatient` state you have to specify the view you are targeting to `homePage@` and don't need to add it again in the `mainCreatePatient.html` template. Also, use a more consistent view name, like: sidebar, main, navbar, etc.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro  I have editted the html files to have a better understanding of what actually I am trying to do. Could you please look at it again?

Comment: There's two states matching the same url pattern (i.e., `url: '/'`). It doesn't seem correct. Also, your code didn't clarified that much what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to change the layout of each state or use the same layout and change the sub view only?

Comment: When I will click the link through ui-sref, it should change the state to "createPatient" and after that the template "./mainCreatePatient.html" should load. In that page, i have a ui-view which will get the child view "patientCreate" from the home state in home.js. This is what I am trying to do !